# How can I modify this PHP code to export profiles inside an array rather than individual objects?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need to pull in a list of profiles from a JSON feed that's being exported from Sugar CRM.

The feed looks like this:

```
{
   "Spencer-Maggie-2020-01-30-20:06:28":{
      "id":"006646f0-439c-11ea-91a3-42010a800003",
      "ethnicity":"White",
      "region":"Southwest",
      "religion":"Christian",
      "children":"no",
      "pets":"yes"
   },
   "Sebastian-Elyse-2020-06-05-19:16:04":{
      "id":"00d4c70a-a761-11ea-8085-42010a800003",
      "ethnicity":"White,Asian,Hispanic",
      "region":"Northeast",
      "religion":"Christian",
      "children":"no",
      "pets":"yes"
   },
   "Warren-Kelly-2021-01-22-15:32:18":{
      "id":"037b8036-5cc7-11eb-9ef4-42010a800003",
      "ethnicity":"White,Hispanic",
      "region":"Southwest",
      "religion":"Christian",
      "children":"yes",
      "pets":"yes"
   }
}
```

I need the profiles to be placed in an array like this:

```
{
   "profiles": [
      {
         "id":"006646f0-439c-11ea-91a3-42010a800003",
         "ethnicity":"White",
         "region":"Southwest",
         "religion":"Christian",
         "children":"no",
         "pets":"yes"
      },
      {
         "id":"00d4c70a-a761-11ea-8085-42010a800003",
         "ethnicity":"White,Asian,Hispanic",
         "region":"Northeast",
         "religion":"Christian",
         "children":"no",
         "pets":"yes"
      },
      {
         "id":"037b8036-5cc7-11eb-9ef4-42010a800003",
         "ethnicity":"White,Hispanic",
         "region":"Southwest",
         "religion":"Christian",
         "children":"yes",
         "pets":"yes"
      }
   ]
}
```

Here's the PHP code that's exporting the profiles from the database to the JSON feed:

```
<?php

global $db, $log;
global $app_list_strings;

$sql = "SELECT p.id, p.date_entered, fc.online_profile_name_c, pc.ethnicity_c AS ethnicity, pc.regions_c AS region, pc.religion_c as religion,
        pc.children_c as children, pc.pets_c as pets, p.description AS text, pc.link_c AS link, pc.video_url_c AS video, pc.placement_made_c, pc.placement_made_date_c
    FROM epi_parent_profiles p
    INNER JOIN epi_parent_profiles_cstm pc ON pc.id_c = p.id
    INNER JOIN epi_family_epi_parent_profiles_1_c fp ON fp.epi_family_epi_parent_profiles_1epi_parent_profiles_idb = p.id AND NOT fp.deleted
    INNER JOIN epi_family f ON f.id = fp.epi_family_epi_parent_profiles_1epi_family_ida AND NOT f.deleted
    INNER JOIN epi_family_cstm fc ON fc.id_c = f.id
    WHERE pc.reviewed_c AND NOT p.deleted";

$res = $db->query(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $sql));

$profiles = array();

while ($row = $db->fetchRow($res)) {

    $profile = $row;

    if (!empty($profile['placement_made_c']) && strtotime('now') - strtotime($profile['placement_made_date_c']) > 1814400) {
        continue;
    }

    $profile['religion'] = str_replace('^', '', $profile['religion']);
    $profile['ethnicity'] = str_replace('^', '', $profile['ethnicity']);

    if ($profile['pets'] == 'NA') {
        $profile['pets'] = '';
    }

    if ($profile['children'] == 'NA') {
        $profile['children'] = '';
    }

    $name = explode(' and ', $profile['online_profile_name_c']);

    $profile['first_name1'] = trim($name[0]);
    $profile['first_name2'] = trim($name[1]);

    $simple_id = $profile['first_name1'] . '-' . $profile['first_name2'] . '-' . date('Y-m-d-H:i:s', strtotime($profile['date_entered']));
    

    $profile['title'] = $simple_id;
    $profile['text'] = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $profile['text']);
    $profile['text'] = htmlentities(htmlentities($profile['text'], ENT_COMPAT), ENT_COMPAT);
    $profile['status'] = !empty($profile['placement_made_c']) ? 'closed' : 'open';
    $profile['link'] = !empty($profile['link']) ? $profile['link'] : 'no_image';

    unset($profile['online_profile_name_c']);
    unset($profile['date_entered']);
    unset($profile['placement_made_c']);
    unset($profile['placement_made_date_c']);

    $profile['paragraphs'] = array();

    $r = $db->query("SELECT par.name AS title, parc.text_c AS text, parc.link_c AS link
        FROM epi_profile_paragraphs par
        INNER JOIN epi_profile_paragraphs_cstm parc ON parc.id_c = par.id
        INNER JOIN epi_parent_profiles_epi_profile_paragraphs_1_c ppp ON ppp.epi_parent1c2eagraphs_idb = par.id AND NOT ppp.deleted
        INNER JOIN epi_parent_profiles pp ON pp.id = ppp.epi_parent0bedrofiles_ida AND NOT pp.deleted
        WHERE pp.id = '".$row['id']."' ORDER BY par.date_entered ASC");

    while ($par = $db->fetchRow($r)) {
        $par['text'] = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $par['text']);
        $par['text'] = htmlentities(htmlentities($par['text'], ENT_COMPAT), ENT_COMPAT);
        $par['link'] = !empty($par['link']) ? $par['link'] : 'no_image';
        $profile['paragraphs'][] = $par;
    }


    $profiles[$simple_id] = $profile;
}
echo json_encode($profiles);
```

I *would* just hop in and fiddle with the PHP until I get what I want but the client doesn't want to grant me access to the CRM due to privacy concerns. They'll apply any modifications I provide to the PHP code but I'm pretty much an HTML/CSS guy and I'm kind of at a loss without the ability to tinker with it myself. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. Your client says they'll provide whatever file you want, so ask them.

Comment: Sorry, they'll apply any modifications I provide to the PHP code. Edited the question for clarity.